# MySQL update query with WHERE clause and INNER JOIN not working

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, where-clause

Can't seem to reach the next step in my update query. I'm able to successfully view columns related to the select no problem:

```
SELECT sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id,sales_flat_order_grid.increment_id,sales_flat_order.coupon_code
FROM sales_flat_order_grid 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order ON sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id     
WHERE sales_flat_order_grid.increment_id = "12345678";
```

This shows 3 columns all where related to the correct increment_id.

The next step is to update the sales_flat_order.coupon_code field. Here is my attempt:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order ON sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id      
WHERE sales_flat_order_grid.increment_id = "12345678"
SET coupon_code = "newcoupon";
```

But I keep getting a ***Not unique table/alias: 'sales_flat_order'*** error message. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the position of `SET` matter? Try placing `SET` as the statement following your `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Is `sales_flat_order` right? in your select you use `sales_flat_order_grid` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The query should be as below, you have joined the same table and hence the problem of unique alias. I have added table alias for better readability.

```
UPDATE 
sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_grid sfog 
ON sfog.entity_id = sfo.entity_id      
SET sfo.coupon_code = "newcoupon"
WHERE sfog.increment_id = "12345678" ;
```

Comment: Thanks Abhik! This was the first working solution without errors from my side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `sales_flat_order` and join on `sales_flat_order_grid` - you've joined on `sales_flat_order`:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_grid 
      ON sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id      
WHERE sales_flat_order_grid.increment_id = "12345678"
SET coupon_code = "newcoupon";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo have two times `sales_flat_order`, change with `sales_flat_order_grid`

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_grid ... -- Need change the namme of the table
```

If you want to join with the same table, use `ALIAS`

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order AS sfo1
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS sfo2 ...
```